# iOS: Perform action after time while user is interacting / scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, performselector

I'm trying to get my application to perform an action after a delay, but it will have to be done WHILE the user is interacting with/scrolling on a `UIScrollView`.

I'm not sure why neither `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` or `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` will fire. Is it because they're on a background thread?

Any suggestions or help?

Comment: What is not working with performSelector: afterDelay:? What is it you are trying to do? Are you SURE they don't fire - i.e you put an NSLog statement in to check?

Comment: I have put in a log statement. It fires after the user stops interacting with the screen. I am trying to update a label.

Comment: I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865760/performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-not-working-from-scrollviewdidzoom, but there isn't any way to incorporate a delay with that.

Comment: Ok, good. Have you tried performSelectorOnMainThread in your timer callback?

Comment: Theres no delay in that, though.

Comment: Have your timer call a method - which THEN calls performSelectorOnMainThread. The timer is doing the delay.

Comment: The timer doesn't work either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both `NSTimer` and `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` by default only fire in the normal run loop mode. When scrolling, the run loop is in event tracking mode.

You have to schedule your timed action in all common modes:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.016 target:self selector:@selector(fire:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

or

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fire:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0 inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```

There's also the dedicated `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`.

Comment: So, its just like what I have in the comment?

Comment: @RileyE I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Which comment?

Comment: Sorry. I'm being very vague! The comment where I mention a post I was looking at before. The post is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865760/performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-not-working-from-scrollviewdidzoom

Comment: Exactly. The answer matches my answer, except for the timer based approach.

Comment: Would you be willing to answer another issue I'm having with this? I'm about to edit my post.

Comment: You should post that as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure the delayed trigger happens on the `NSRunLoopCommonModes`. The default is `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` which won't get messages while e.g. scrolling.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fire:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0 inModes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```

Alternatively you can use `GCD` which also behaves the same way (not sure which runloop mode it uses)

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift:

```
performSelector(#selector(fire:), withObject: sender, afterDelay: 1.0, inModes: [NSRunLoopCommonModes])
```